# TKInter Python checkbutton state

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to do some work on a text file if certain checkbuttons are checked.

```
"Populate CheckBoxes"
Label(master, text="Pick at least one index:").grid(row=4, column=1)
Checkbutton(master, text="Short",variable=var1).place(x=5,y=60)
Checkbutton(master, text="Standard",variable=var2).place(x=60,y=60)
Checkbutton(master, text="Long",variable=var3).place(x=130,y=60)
```

Calling

```
print("Short: %d,\nStandard: %d,\nLong: %d" % (var1.get(), var2.get(), 
      var3.get()))
```

prints out 0 or 1 for each variable but when I am trying to use that value to do something it does'nt seem to call the code.

```
if var2.get(): <--- does this mean if = 1?
    Do something
```

Comment: In `if something:`, `something` will be considered True if it is not `False`, `0`, `[]`, `''`, `{}`, `None`, ... Most empty objects (list, dictionary, string, tuple, ...) are considered False, but everything else is considered `True` (not only 1)

Comment: How are `var1`, `var2`, `var3` declared exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below example `var.get()`'s value is printed in command prompt if it's `False` and updates the `lbl['text']` if it's `True`:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

lbl = tkinter.Label(root)
lbl.pack()

var = tkinter.BooleanVar()

def update_lbl():
    global var
    if var.get():
        lbl['text'] = str(var.get())
    else:
        print(var.get())

tkinter.Checkbutton(root, variable=var, command=update_lbl).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

But below code never `print`s as `"0"` and `"1"` are both `True`:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

lbl = tkinter.Label(root)
lbl.pack()

var = tkinter.StringVar()

def update_lbl():
    global var
    if var.get():
        lbl['text'] = str(var.get())
    else:
        print(var.get())

tkinter.Checkbutton(root, variable=var, command=update_lbl).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the reason though that when i've clicked the var2 checkbox its not the completing the action of the if statement?

Comment: @JonLavercombe are they objects of `StringVar`?

Comment: No they are just exactly as listed above, so if i convert them to string... something like if str(var2.get()):

Comment: @JonLavercombe `var1`, `var2`, `var3` should all be `tkinter.BooleanVar` or at worst `tkinter.IntVar` otherwise they may act unpredictably.